# Any Calendar control that allows data binding for Universal Windows app?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

We need to display events on a monthly/weekly calendar.

The **CalendarView** control in XAML is too limited in function.

And [the calendar sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Calendar) just deals with date data processing.

Is there anything that works like jQuery FullCalendar [[link](http://fullcalendar.io/)], which I can add events data source by parsing my **.ics** calendar file?

Comment: What specific functions are you missing? The control is actually quite complex if you know how to deal with the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` event, see the example at the bottom of this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.aspx

Comment: Just want to know if we can just provide a data source and the data binding can layout events for us. Just like FullCalendar does.